# RootFolder.SubFolders problem

Tags: powershell, library, download

I am able to search all folders with their name by using

```
$folder.Name.StartsWith("a")
```

this will display all folders which starts with name a in a Document Library.

I want all folders to be searched only from root level of Document library with name "a" and it should include all its subfolders inside it which can starts with any letter but property StartWith() doesn't exist for $RootFolder.SubFolders

any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

`$RootFolder.SubFolders` will give you the collection of folders. Loop through the collection and use `StartsWith` with each folder:

```
$folders =  $RootFolder.SubFolders;
foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    if ($folder.Name.StartsWith("a"))
    {
         // Call $folder.Subfolders again to get folders present in this folder
         // Then use foreach to loop thru each folder and get files inside them
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Once inside the folder, call `SubFolders` again on the folder and then loop through all those folders to get files inside them.

Comment: what you have given is correct. but my requirement was to download all folders with name" a" at $RootFolder.SubFolders and also it should download all folders inside those folders which can starts with any name.

Comment: You did not mention about downloading in the question, even though I can see the download tag. But it will be better if you update the question

Comment: yes.i will update the question. but any work around for it?

Comment: See my update answer

Comment: Nadeem one more problem.i am ble to get folder level only till root subfolders..how to interate all folder levels